# iOS downloading large file using AFNetworking stops

Tags: ios, download, afnetworking, nsoutputstream

I'm downloading a large video file using AFNetworking and it seems to stop at around 170MB without calling a timeout or throwing any other kind of error.

I have subclassed AFURLConnectionOperation to stream the data and am using an NSOutputStream to write the data straight to a file.

```
NSOutputStream * output = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:appFile append:NO];
urlConnection = [[RADVideoDownloader alloc]initWithRequest:request andOutputStream:output];
```

[urlConnection start];

The file itself is around 370MB. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance